# Proof that a connected subset of a disconnected metric space is entirely contained in one of the separated sets

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

I'm trying to prove the following proposition:

Let (A, B) form a separation of a metric space (M, d), meaning that (M, d) is disconnected. If N is a connected subset of M, I need to show that either N is entirely contained in A or entirely contained in B.

Here's my approach so far:

1. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that N is not entirely contained in A or B.
2. Without loss of generality, assume there is at least one point x in N that is in A, and there is at least one point y in N that is in B.
3. $N_a \cup N_b$ where $N_a = N \cap A$ and $N_b = N \cap B$.

I wish to show $N_a \cup N_b$ is not N

I'm stuck at this point and need help in completing the proof. Any insights or guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide a detailed explanation or proof sketch to help me understand and complete this proof. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N \cap A$ and $N \cap B$ are two disjoint sets which are open in $N$ under the subspace topology. Since $N$ is connected, one of them must be empty. Conclude that consequently, $N \subseteq A$ or $N \subseteq B$.